# How to improve a JWT access token and refresh token based on authentication with Oauth2 protocol?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I have built one authentication using access token, refresh token and refresh token rotation. When a user login, the system generates one JWT token and one UUID hashed refresh token and its refresh token id then return back to user.

The init refresh token is a UUID token and it uses `bcrypt` to hash the uuid token then saving on the database. On the database, apart from saving the refresh token id and the hashed token, I also saved its expired date, its userId, active status and revoked ip.

The access token is passed inside `Authentication` header as a `Bearer` token for JWT verify. When one access token is expired, it calls `/refresh-token` with the old refresh token value and its id to get a new access token and refresh token pair. If the refresh token is expired, I will ask the user to login again.

I also have a refresh token rotation method to avoid refresh token reusing. When a refresh token reused, I will revoke and disable all the refresh tokens belonging to that userId family. So the user should login again to get the new access token and refresh token pair.

I know `OAuth2` is a good protocol to implement access token and refresh token authentication. With my authentication design, how to improve it to make it with `OAuth2`?

Answer (score 2):

Well it sounds like your UUID has all the powers of a refresh token to a client. And if the client is a browser it should never receive a refresh token - a secure cookie is considered better.

The main things I would recommend are the use an Authorization Server and to follow standard guidance around APIs, web and mobile apps.

OAuth provides a number of security design patterns. It is worth understanding the specifics of web and mobile clients. Also think about security related features such as auditing of tokens issued.

Here are some resources from Curity, where I work. The concepts here apply to any provider - it is the principles that matter:

- [IAM Primer](https://curity.io/resources/learn/iam-primer/)
- [Free Authorization Server](https://curity.io/product/community/)
- [Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/)

Comment: Hi, why cookie is more secure than the response body on the refresh token?

Comment: Refresh tokens in a response body are fine if the client can store them securely but a browser cannot. In 2021 there are concerns about XSS in the browser and the latest `SameSite=strict` cookies are preferred. See [this video](https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/talks/xssoauth.html). As you can see there are often different concerns depending on the type of client.